# Not able to connect to Redshift server using postgresql or redshift driver

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a code which connects to redshift server and gets some table entry. When I run it locally it works fine. But when I build it as a jar and run it on hadoop then I am getting this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

I have added this in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also added the jar file location in HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable in hadoop-env.sh.
Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the location of my jar and it is working now. I still don't understand why it was not picking up the jar from previous path.